# Excel danish region change TT:MM

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im on a danish pc, and I have a formula where I change a date to text.
`=TEXT(B7;"TT:MM")`

if my collouge from Italy opens this, it fails. and in my danish model i cannot use `HH:MM`.
I have tried applying a locale, but it does not work for me: `=TEXT(D4;"[$-0406]TT:MM")`
So How do I make the formula universal? For years in DK we use `ÅÅÅÅ`, in english its `YYYY`.

Comment: I linked you to a Q&A that I suspect will solve your issue. Let me know if it worked. You can use the `INDEX(GET.WORKSPACE(37), 22)` for the hour symbol and index 23 for the minutes.